# Cloning an object in java: org.objenesis.ObjenesisException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: newInstance [class java.lang.Class, int]

Tags: java, android, cloneable

I am using Espresso to test my application.

I am also using the library `uk.com.robust-it:cloning`  ([Java Deep Cloning Library](https://code.google.com/p/cloning/))  version **1.9.2** to clone an object.

If I am using the application, I have no exception, but when the tests are running, I have the following exception:

```
org.objenesis.ObjenesisException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: newInstance [class java.lang.Class, int]
            at org.objenesis.instantiator.android.AndroidInstantiator.getNewInstanceMethod(AndroidInstantiator.java:62)
            at org.objenesis.instantiator.android.AndroidInstantiator.<init>(AndroidInstantiator.java:38)
            at org.objenesis.strategy.StdInstantiatorStrategy.newInstantiatorOf(StdInstantiatorStrategy.java:75)
            at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.getInstantiatorOf(ObjenesisBase.java:90)
            at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:73)
            at com.rits.cloning.ObjenesisInstantiationStrategy.newInstance(ObjenesisInstantiationStrategy.java:18)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.newInstance(Cloner.java:271)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:436)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.deepClone(Cloner.java:301)
```

Does someone also have this exception?

This guy has the same problem that I ...

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/objenesis-dev/jdqWCwy5E78